# how to filter records with calculated value in elasticsearch geodistance when compared to another field

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-5

I have an elasticsearch index of products which has nested array of stores. Now i need to search for store which

1. is within the user's input range, which can be changed by user (1 to 5000km)
2. the store delivers to the user's current location

```
{
    "createdBy" : "60fc25d58d1ae5473df84f13",
    "creationTime" : "2021-10-08T18:39:40.482Z",
    "lastModifiedBy" : "60fc25d58d1ae5473df84f13",
    "lastModificationTime" : "2021-10-09T15:17:07.97Z",
    "title" : "Product Name 1",
    "shortDesc" : "HpEtRod",
    "id" : "6160906c30ff430f14eda4c9",
    "longDesc" : "qOrfynF",
    "categoryId" : "6160906c5593ee07c5e288e8",
    "categoryName" : "GhwhcCk",
    "stores" : [
      {
        "id" : "616061b6b202bc39a874061a",
        "name" : "Store1 Name XYA",
        "logo" : null,
        "quantity" : 0,
        "active" : true,
        "price" : {
          "mrp" : 42.0,
          "sp" : 38.0
        },
        "location" : {
          "geoPoint" : {
            "lon" : 75.7764236,
            "lat" : 26.9408629
          }
        },
        "deliverableDistance":2 //in Km
      },
      {
        "id" : "60d6ff35a790ed1956d16ef6",
        "name" : "Store2 kjebbj",
        "logo" : null,
        "quantity" : 0,
        "active" : true,
        "price" : {
          "mrp" : 82.0,
          "sp" : 78.0
        },
        "location" : {
          "geoPoint" : {
            "lon" : 75.760570,
            "lat" : 26.970208
          }
        },
        "deliverableDistance":3 //in Km
      }
    ],
    "....":"...."
  }
```

Current Query that i'm using which contains user current location & search distance range. It does filtering only for the distance, but i'm not able to figure how to do one more level of filter based on store's delivery distance range.

```
GET /product/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "title": "Product"
          }
        }
      ],
      "should": [
        {
          
          "nested": {
            "path": "stores",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "filter": [
                  {
                    "geo_distance": {
                      "distance": "10km", // user input, search distance range.
                      "stores.location.geoPoint": { // current user location
                        "lat": 26.944535,
                        "lon": 75.7747515
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            },
            "inner_hits": {
              
            }
          }
          
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

E.g. user current location is

1. 2Km from Store1
2. 10Km from Store2

And:

1. Store1 delivers within a distance of 3Km &
2. Store2 delivers within a distance of 4Km &

Now, when user will search within a range of 50Km, then i only need to include store1, but not Store2. Reason:

1. Include Store1, because user current location is within store1's delivery range (2Km<=3Km true)
2. DONT INCLUDE Store2, because user current location is NOT within store2's delivery range (10Km <= 4Km , false)

please help me on this.

Comment: Have you resolved the issue, I'm also facing the same issue. plz let me know...

Comment: No, still looking for an answer.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71323314/4909563
you can find here

Comment: @zulqarnain refer below answer.

Answer (score -1):

Wanted to share my knowledge:
i tried @zulqarnain referred answer, but that seems too slow and ain't good with performance.
Rather, what i suggest is to pre-compute the data and then perform quick search.

As part of the answer suggested by @zulqarnain , we are computing the records (by calculating distance) at every request, which will be too slow because the script needs to be executed for all requests.

What i prefer is: create a circle at a coordinate with X radius and store those coordinates (coordinates of circle) , and then use elastic search geo query to check whether the user location is within that circle or not. This will be a lot faster.